# Adding multiple class tags to MVC HTML helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I need to assign multiple classes to an MVC TextBox HTML helper, so it functions the same as when assigning multiple classes to an HTML element.

i.e.: `<div class="class1, class2"></div>`

The following does not work properly:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "class1, class2" })
```

Note: I need to add both class names to a single element in order to trigger different jQuery functions. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Close:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "class1 class2" })
```

...produces the following HTML:

```
<input class="class1 class2" data-val="true" data-val-required="Name is required" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
```